# Div centered in another div

Tags: css, html

i'm trying to center the div inside another div.

This is my HTML

```
<div id="runway-category">
   <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" class="runway-category-posts">
      <div class="photo"><?php custom_get_post_attachments(get_the_ID(), $__width, $__height, get_the_title()); ?><div class="runway-title"><?php the_title(); ?></div></div>
   </a>         
</div>
```

And this is CSS

```
.runway-category-posts{width:298px;height:500px;margin: 0 9px 18px 9px;float:left;display:block;}
.runway-title{text-align:center;font-family:tall_film;color:#FFF;font-size:20px;}
```

Whats should i add to css to do it right?

EDIT - The div which should be centered in PHOTO div is RUNWAY-TITLE

Comment: try `margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;` to particular `div`

Comment: http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/css-vertical-center-solution.html

Answer (score 0):

whichever div is not being centered (you dont specify which). set

```
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

that should do the trick.

Comment: I need to center it verticaly

Comment: A quick google search resulted in: http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/vertical-centering-with-css/

Answer (score 0):

just assign height and width to inner div.put margin-left and margin-right of innerdiv to 'auto'.

Comment: I need to center it verticaly.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this sample i made for you i think it will do the trick

[**Demo Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Vinay199129/Y8RZa/3/)

```
#runway-category {
text-align:center;
border: 1px solid black;
}
.runway-category-posts {
margin: 2px;
}
.photo {
margin:0px 25px 0px 25px;
border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use "
div style="background:green;width:200;height:200;position:absolute;"
div style="background:red;width:100;height:100;margin:auto;position:absolute;top:0;bottom:0;left:0;right:0;"

/div
/div"